# MPEG-7 low-level audio descriptors

Tags: audio, feature-extraction

I'm working on an application which need to use the full set of 17 MPEG-7 low-level descriptors. Is there any library I can use for it? Preferably with a Python wrapper/API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did some research on existing implementations of the MPEG-7 audio descriptors and found the following implementations:

- The official implementation of the 17 low-level descriptors ([part 1](http://mpeg7.doc.gold.ac.uk/mirror/zips/Matlab-XM-v1.zip) and [part 2](http://mpeg7.doc.gold.ac.uk/mirror/zips/Matlab-XM-v2.zip)) (MATLAB).

Alghough the descriptors are implemented in MATLAB, it should not be a big issue to implement them in Python, based on the MATLAB code. Maybe the following resources are also of interest:

- The [Timbre Toolbox](http://recherche.ircam.fr/pub/timbretoolbox/timbretoolbox.zip), which implements a number of features described in [this JASA article](https://www.mcgill.ca/mpcl/files/mpcl/peeters_2011_jasa.pdf), which include some of the MPEG-7 audio descriptors (MATLAB) and
- An an [online computation of all 17 audio descriptors](http://mpeg7lld.nue.tu-berlin.de/) with the MPEG-7 Low Level Descriptor Extractor of the TU Berlin.

Comment: I'm sorry I think you understood me incorrectly, I meant audio features not video. They are described in http://mpeg7.org/audio-descriptors/

Comment: No problem. I just edited the answer to hopefully provide the information you are looking for.

Comment: This one is also pretty useful http://mpeg7.doc.gold.ac.uk/